# Prevent multiple clicks on button

Tags: javascript, html

I've a small quiz which has 3 questions. I want to count points if user clicks correct answer. I made it but it counts me all clicks (even the user clicks many times on the same answer). How to prevent it?

```
<section>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum1</p>
    <button class="answer">14</button>
    <button class="answer">18</button>
    <button class="answer correct">23</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Lorem Ipsum2</p>
    <button class="answer">Kalisz</button>
    <button class="answer correct">Poznań</button>
    <button class="answer">Łódź</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Lorem Ipsum3</p>
    <button class="answer correct">Paulina</button>
    <button class="answer">Wanda</button>
    <button class="answer">Ania</button>
    <br />
</section>
```

**JS**

```
// Variables
var correct = document.getElementsByClassName('correct');
var sum = 0;

// Points sum
for(var i=0; i < correct.length; i++)
 correct[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(){
 sum +=1;
});
```

Comment: Either disable the button on click, or set a flag if it has already been clicked and only count if not

Comment: Have you tried  $('.correct').attr('disabled',true); ?

Comment: I would like do it in clean JS, so I want to avoid jQuery

Comment: It's also not correct as it would disable all .correct buttons @Abdenn0ur

Comment: What do you think about adding radio buttons in HTML?

Comment: add : this.disabled=true; but that's not the best a quiz script as it will gray-out the correct answer, this is when CSS comes in handy though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your javascript code to this:

```
// Zmienne
var correct = document.getElementsByClassName('correct');
var sum = 0;

function increaseScore() {
    sum +=1;
    console.log(sum);
    this.removeEventListener('click', increaseScore);
}
// Sumowanie punktów
for(var i=0; i < correct.length; i++)
    correct[i].addEventListener( 'click', increaseScore);
```

This increases the sum on the first click, and removes event listener for the button clicked afterwards, so the sum will be increased only once.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the click handler after the first click

```js
// Zmienne
var correct = document.getElementsByClassName("correct");
var sum = 0;
function updateCountDisplay () {
  document.getElementById('count').innerText = sum

}

function handleClick(elm) {
  elm.addEventListener("click", function handler() {
    elm.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    sum++;
    updateCountDisplay()
  });
}

updateCountDisplay();

// Sumowanie punktów
for (var i = 0; i < correct.length; i++) {
  handleClick(correct[i]);
}
```

```html
<section>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum1</p>
    <button class="answer">14</button>
    <button class="answer">18</button>
    <button class="answer correct">23</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Lorem Ipsum2</p>
    <button class="answer">Kalisz</button>
    <button class="answer correct">Poznań</button>
    <button class="answer">Łódź</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Lorem Ipsum3</p>
    <button class="answer correct">Paulina</button>
    <button class="answer">Wanda</button>
    <button class="answer">Ania</button>
    <br />
</section>
<div>
  correct count <span id="count"></span>
</div>
```